# Consider the definition of the Limit of a Sequence with modifications.

Tags: real-analysis

The definition of the Limit of a Sequence, as given by my text, is the following: Let {s$_n$} be a sequence of real number. We say that {s$_n$} converges to a number L and write:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = L$$we can also write it: $s_n$ approaches L as n approaches infinity (provided that for every number $\epsilon > 0$ there is an integer $N$ so that $|s_n - L| < \epsilon$ whenever n $\ge$ N. Now, consider the following modification to the definition...

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = L$$ provided that for every positive integer m there is a real number N such that $|s_n-L| < \frac{1}{m}$ whenever n $\ge$ N.

From what I gather, in the original definition N depends on $\epsilon$, $N(\epsilon)$.

In the modified definition, N depends on the positive integer m, $N(m)$.

How are these definitions equal to one another?

Comment: Just take $\;\epsilon=\frac1m\;$ ...it's exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: Both definition of convergence of a sequence are logically equivalent

Sketch proof:
Suppose $(a_n)$ converges using the $\varepsilon$ definition then taking $\varepsilon=1/m$ satisfy the $1/m$ definition. For the converse suppose $(a_n)$ converges using $1/m$ definition. We'd like to show that also converges using a $\varepsilon$ definition. So given $\varepsilon>0$ if we take $1/m<\varepsilon$ then this implies the other converges. Thus both are logically equivalent.